# Inserting using a select with or

Tags: mysql

I am trying to to perform an insert using the following:

```
INSERT INTO stock_withholds (s_id, mob, paddock, product, completed_date, withhold_until_date, ESI_withhold_until_date)
   SELECT stk_id AS s_id,
           mob,
           paddock,
           product,
           completed_date,
           withhold_until_date,
           ESI_withhold_until_date
   FROM stock_current
   WHERE (withhold_until_date >=CURDATE()
   OR (ESI_withhold_until_date >= CURDATE()
   AND stock_current.stk_id NOT IN
   (SELECT s_id
   FROM stock_withholds)
```

If I rerun the query it duplicates the records.

Desired result is if either the withhold_until_date or ESI_withhold_until_date are greater then current date the records would inserted.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/1427878, and then format your code properly.

Comment: I think you are missing brackets in WHERE condition, don't you?

Comment: Thanks Alexander

Comment: You can only run the query one time per day because you looking for >=CURDATE(). Otherwiese the records are duplicated. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No iLikeMySql the above answer answer my question and the results are as they should be. Thanks for you time and effort